# filter(x %in% vector), when vector comes from a filtered dataframe

Tags: r, filtering

Yes, I use dplyr and base. I understand data.table is great but at the moment, I'd like to stay in the realm of what I know, please do not offer solutions outside of base or tidyverse if it can be managed.

Basically, I'd like to find a more efficient way of filtering some dataframes without needing to create so many objects.

Below is what I've been doing, Id like to just do the following within the same chain/object. Ideally, the solution would allow me to continue the chain afterwards with other dplyr functions.

```
DF1<-Booked%>%
     filter(Type=="A")

DF2<-Billed%>%
     filter(Material_Number %in% DF1$Material_Number)
```

Im sure there's a more direct way. Forgive me I'm sort of a novice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's easier to help if there's a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Otherwise we're just guessing as to what specifically you're working with

Answer (score 0):

Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and post sample data and expected output, but you probably need something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

Billed %>%
  inner_join(filter(Booked, Type == "A"), by = "Material_Number")
```

OR:

```
Booked %>%
  filter(Type == "A") %>% 
  right_join(Billed, by = "Material_Number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a combination of both:

```
DF2 <- Billed%>%
   filter(Material_Number %in% Booked[Booked$Type=="A",]$Material_Number)
```

or

```
DF2 <- Billed%>%
   filter(Material_Number %in% Booked[Booked$Type=="A","Material_Number"])
```